# heroku: Running console attached to terminal...

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple rails application to an heroku account, I was able to login and push, only it seems to hang when I try to 
    heroku run rake db:migrate

or to

```
heroku run console
```

I get the message

```
Running console attached to terminal...
```

and then nothing happens... it just hangs. I read that it could be I have some blocked ports (like, port 5000) but it seems quite strange to me, I never had such problems before...

I am on Ubuntu, how can I check if that's the case? or how could I fix the issue? Anybody got any hint? I already tried to heroku update, same issue...

Comment: Sounds weird, because when you run that command it may take a while and produce no output.
Does the logs point any error? `heroku logs`

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582860/heroku-run-console-get-timeout-awaiting-process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582860/heroku-run-console-get-timeout-awaiting-process)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its the port problem i also face the same issue a while ago and their support guys told me top make open the port.

Here is their reply

This problem is typically caused by a connectivity or firewall issue. You can test your connection to our heroku run and heroku console servers by running the following commands:

```
telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
telnet s1.runtime.heroku.com 5000
```

Some users have success after whitelisting these hostname+port combinations in their firewall. We recommend contacting your IT department to move forward with this issue.

If you are successfully able to connect, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (right bracket) and then type quit to exit the telnet session.

An application which takes a long time to boot can also exasperate connectivity issues. If the server does not respond quickly enough, your local connection will timeout before the app can boot.

Comment: I was having the same problem, it worked for me. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: a better solution to this is mentioned in [stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546803/heroku-run-console-returns-error-connecting-to-process).. use 'heroku run:detached rake db:migrate' instead of 'heroku run rake db:migrate'

Answer (score -2):

To test the net enabled access to that port try the following. They mention that filtered-port issue on [their guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps).

```
$ telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
```