# heroku console No route to host error

Tags: ruby, bash, heroku

I have a simple Ruby app hosted on Heroku. It is not Rails app, it only uses Rack and Sinatra and it is running on `cedar-14` stack.
When I try to run `heroku run console` or `heroku run bash` it prompts:

```
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       No route to host - connect(2) (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
```

Also, when I try to telnet as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888822/heroku-running-console-attached-to-terminal) It prompts just the same

```
$ telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
Trying 50.19.103.36...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

and

```
$ telnet s1.runtime.heroku.com 5000
telnet: could not resolve s1.runtime.heroku.com/5000: Name or service not known
```

I'm not premium Heroku user.
Can I get that One-Off dyno and If I can how?

Comment: Can you push?  It seems like you have network or firewall issues.

Comment: Yes I can push, log, config ...