# Running Heroku Console does not start

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, console

I am trying to run Heroku console, but in the console, I get the message **"Running console attached to terminal"** but the console doesn't start.

In the Heroku logs, I get the error:

```
 Error: no child processes attached.
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm encountering similar issue; Output from my Heroku logs:

2012-02-24T07:54:31+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-02-24T07:54:38+00:00 app[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-02-24T07:54:38+00:00 app[run.1]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2012-02-24T07:54:39+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-02-24T07:54:39+00:00 app[run.1]: Error: undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass
2012-02-24T07:54:40+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-02-24T07:54:40+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete

Comment: ~/rails/recruits => heroku run rails console
Running rails console attached to terminal... up, run.1
~/rails/recruits =>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had a thread with Heroku support about my similar issue, here was their response, which worked for me.

> So this is a bamboo app. You can either do
>
> $ heroku console
>
> which will tap into a running web dyno, or you can run a new console
>   as a one-off process with:
>
> $ heroku run bundle exec rails console
>
> On cedar apps you'd also be able to do
>
> $ heroku run console
>
> which also starts a one-off process, because the console process type
>   would be implied by the rails buildpack or declared in your Procfile.
>   It amounts to the same as the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing same issues.
Try

> heroku run rails console

in **Rails >=3**

Happy coding :)

Comment: heroku run console --app {your-app-name}

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
```

to test the net enabled access to that port. They mention that filtered-port issue on [their guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps)

Comment: Ultimately, this is heroku not taking responsibility to help users workaround draconian environments.  They need to fix this by adding a port 80 or 443 solution.

Comment: I think port 80 should not be used for non-http communications.

Comment: Then don't use websockets. :) Sometimes you have to work around the way things are to get a job done so you can get home.

Comment: Check out corkscrew http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem you're describing and it has an accepted answer which seemed to fix the issue for the guy that posted the question :-)

[heroku run console returns 'Error connecting to process'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546803/heroku-run-console-returns-error-connecting-to-process)

Comment: Its a different issue for me as well.  Its returning no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before I'd actually pushed my code to heroku.

Once I successfully pushed and started everything (bundle, rake etc.) the console actually worked.

Comment: everything appears to be there on my end, ut I'm having the same problem as Tony.

Answer (score -1):

Do this and then try
In Procfile

web: bundle exec unicorn_rails -p $PORT -c config/unicorn.rb

In unicorn.rb

worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

@resque_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @resque_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=*")
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

Comment: Unicorn is not relevant here. Was this meant for another question perhaps?