# Error in git push heroku master through ssh behind proxy

Tags: git, heroku

**Brief Context:**
Hi, I am a university student (behind proxy 10.3.100.211:8080), new to ROR, Git & Heroku and have been following Ruby on Rails tutorial. I solved the problem of pushing git repo through ssh using following config in my ~/.ssh/config file (and it worked perfectly after that):

```
Host github.com  
Hostname ssh.github.com  
User git  
ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p  
Port 443
```

**Problem:**

However, on following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git to use heroku for online app deployment, I am getting following error:

```
$git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My current status is: $ git remote -v

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:deep-dusk-1030.git (fetch)  
heroku  git@heroku.com:deep-dusk-1030.git (push)  
origin  git@github.com:shaileshgupta/testapp.git (fetch)  
origin  git@github.com:shaileshgupta/testapp.git (push)
```

Can anyone help me with github.com like settings for heroku.com to be written in my ~/.ssh/config file for seamless connection through ssh behind proxy using PORT 443/22.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update (Some More Information)**
I tried following settings and got following errors:

Configuration:

```
Host heroku.com  
  Hostname ssh.heroku.com  
  User git  
  ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p  
  Port 443
```

Error:

```
$ git push heroku master  
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Another Configuration:

```
Host github.com, heroku.com  
  Hostname ssh.github.com  
  User git  
  ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p  
  Port 443
```

Error:

```
$ git push heroku master  
ERROR: Repository not found.  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: So...don't you need the same proxy configuration to reach `heroku.com` as you need to reach `github.com`?

Comment: I tried it, but it is showing following error: 
**$ git push heroku master**
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Comment: Is there any problem with using ssh.heroku.com as Hostname? Does heroku also uses ssh.heroku.com as Hostname as github uses ssh.github.com for Hostname?

Comment: hey guys, can someone upvote this question to have an answer to it? @larsks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your .ssh/config write this :

```
Host git_heroku
  Hostname heroku.com
  User git
  ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p
  Port 443
```

and in your .git/config change

```
git@heroku.com
```

to

```
git_heroku
```

The full line for a remote will look something like:

```
[remote "appname"]
  url = git_heroku:appname.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/appname/*
```

`git_heroku` is an alias; you need to change your git config to use that alias.

Comment: Can you give me an example of exactly how my .git/config file should look? What do you mean, "change it for use alias"

Comment: @Daniel Hey I copyedited this answer - hopefuly it's a bit more clear. I added what I *think* should go in the git config file, but let me know if it works for you.

Comment: When you say "git_heroku is an alias", you mean an alias for git@heroku.com, right? So the line in the config file should be: [alias]
 git_heroku = git@heroku.com ...is that right?

Comment: No, it's a ssh alias, because you write in the .ssh/config.

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer above in your .ssh/config:

- use `ssh.heroku.com` for `Hostname` instead of `heroku.com`
- make sure you include your identity file `IdentityFile "path to identity file"`
- don't specify `Port`

So my .ssh/config file looks something like this:

```
Host git_heroku
ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.usurt.ru 3128 %h %p
HostName ssh.heroku.com
User git
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

And appropriate lines in .git/config file:

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git_heroku:still-taiga-2820.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```