# Push to heroku through Proxy server

Tags: git, heroku

I have installed Heroku and set up an account but cannot push code for my app onto it, due to a proxy in my university.

I tried using the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy) thread and I read [this](http://tachang.tumblr.com/post/22265579539/using-github-through-draconian-proxies-windows-and) page about getting github to work through a proxy, but I still get an error, which is:

```
$git push heroku origin
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$git remote -v
heroku  git_heroku:secret-hamlet-7718.git (fetch)
heroku  git_heroku:secret-hamlet-7718.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/saasbook/hw2_rottenpotatoes.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/saasbook/hw2_rottenpotatoes.git (push)
```

My .ssh/config file contains:

```
ProxyCommand corkscrew [proxy_address] [proxy_port] %h %p

Host git_heroku
  Hostname heroku.com
  User git
  Port 443
```

The relevant portion of .git/config file:

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git_heroku:secret-hamlet-7718.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

I am pretty sure I have missed something. I hope someone can point out what.

Comment: You may try to connect to Heroku via tunneling. Please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877088/connecting-to-heroku-using-port-443/19536371#19536371)

Answer (score 1):

Does changing your `[remote "heroku"]` to this help?

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku:secret-hamlet-7718.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and put the ProxyCommand within the `Host` section:

```
Host git_heroku
  Hostname heroku.com
  User git
  ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p
  Port 443
```