# Connecting to Heroku using port 443

Tags: heroku, ssh

I'm a university student and all ports except 80, 443 are blocked. I'm able to connect to github via

```
Host github.com                                                                                    
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

`git push heroku master` gives me this error:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891991/push-to-heroku-through-proxy-server) on SO but I've still not got it working. Is there a way I can connect to heroku do deploy my websites?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you modify both your .ssh/config and your .git/config as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11158724/28037)? What error message are you getting after the modifications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your SSH port been blocked and wish to push into heroku using alternate port then you may consider **Tunneling**.

For tunneling you are required to have additional PC or Server resides outside of blocked network and having access to Port 22.

For the scenario below we can use house PC to tunnel into heroku server.  Since the university network only allow Port 80 and 443, we can set the House PC to receive connection via port 443 and tunnel it to port 22.

**At House PC:**

1. Configure SSH server in the house PC to  run on port 443.  [Refer here to configure SSH Server on Multiple Ports](http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2006/10/11/running-an-ssh-server-on-multiple-ports)

**University PC:**

1. Configure University PC to resolve git_tunnel alias to point to localhost on port 9001. Edit `~/.ssh/config` and add following

   ```
   # ~/.ssh/config

   Host git_tunnel
      Hostname 127.0.0.1
      User git
      Port 9001
   ```
2. Add a new remote alias as `tunnel` which will point to `git@git_tunnel:{app name}.git`

   `git remote add tunnel git@git_tunnel:{app name}.git`
3. From the University PC establish tunnel to house PC which listening on port 443.

   `ssh -L 9001:heroku.com:22 -p 443 root@housepc.com`
4. Deploy to heroku using alias `tunnel` created earlier

   `git push tunnel master`

Comment: Alternatively you may use publicly available VPN e.g https://hide.me/ and enjoy using any port nuumber you want.

Answer (score 7):

Heroku ssh only works over port 22. There is, however, a plugin that lets you push via HTTP. It does not use git, though. Instead, you `heroku push`.

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push