# push to heroku through port 443

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I am unable to use the default port 22 and so have run into difficulties setting up git and heroku according to the hartl rails tutorial.

I was able to push to git by including the following in the ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host github.com
User git
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

However, a similar entry does not work for heroku:

```
Host heroku.com
User git
Hostname ssh.heroku.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

It seems to hang at this debug line:

```
  debug1: identity file /c/Users/[my folder name]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

...before failing with this message:

```
  ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.
```

I had hopes for this answer, 
[Error in git push heroku master through ssh behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy)
it doesn't work for me either...

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: BTW, I just saw where you are trying to go through the rails tutorial. My answer may be heavy for that purpose, but if you *just can't* hit 22, get somewhere you can, or just skip the heroku bits.

Comment: I've already gone through the tut, skipping heroku, but now I'm trying to do some stuff at work and wanted to put it up. I guess I'll do the development at work, push it to github and push it to heroku from home. I was just hoping there might be a similarly easy solution as there was for the same issue with github...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heroku is working on providing alternative ways to move source code onto the platform, take a look at `heroku push`, for example: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push

It uses https and is thus not susceptible to the firewall-blocking you're experiencing.

**UPDATE**

Heroku now has [beta HTTP Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git) support. If the problem is caused by you being unable to access Heroku on port 22, then HTTP Git should solve it (it works on port 443).

To use HTTP Git, first make sure Toolbelt is updated and that your credentials are current:

```
$ heroku update
$ heroku login
```

(this is important because Heroku HTTP Git authenticates in a slightly different way than the rest of Toolbelt)

During the beta, you get HTTP by passing the `--http-git` flag to the relevant `heroku apps:create`, `heroku git:clone` and `heroku git:remote` commands. To create a new app and have it be configured with a HTTP Git remote, run this:

```
$ heroku apps:create --http-git
```

To change an existing app from SSH to HTTP Git, simply run this command from the app’s directory on your machine:

```
$ heroku git:remote --http-git
Git remote heroku updated
```

Check out the [Dev Center documentation for details on how set up HTTP Git for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git).

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I'm impressed that github had the foresight to run ssh on 443. It's likely that heroku is just running https, which obviously wouldn't allow you to establish an ssh connection to git over.

Since github is working for you, why not leverage that? Use a service like travisci to watch github, build, and deploy to heroku.

A simple example using travis: http://metabates.com/2012/10/23/deploying-to-heroku-from-travisci/