# Unable to push to Heroku remote?

Tags: git, heroku, github, ssh

I recently started using heroku and while I was going through their tutorial of **"Getting started with Java"** https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#set-up

I encountered the following problem while pushing my local branch to the Remote repo[ after having followed the previous steps viz, installing heroku toolbelt,cloning some repo(which they have given) creating heroku remote with Heroku create, generating a new key and adding it to heroku.]
But when Im trying to push it to my remote heroku repo with **`git push heroku master`** im getting the following error:

> **ssh:** heroku.com: no address associated with name
>   **fatal:** Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Validating the connection also gives this error:
`ssh -v git@heroku.com`

> **ssh**: heroku.com: no address associated with name

I tried googling around(and checking other stackoverflow questions) but the most i could get was that I have to create a config file and write few stuff in it,but sadly that dint work.Then I thought there might be a problem with my shh keys so i tried removing them and adding only single key again but that also didnt work.Finally I tried it on linux but i was getting the same error!

---

PS:Im using windows 8.1 on a proxy server(can that be a problem? :/ )

Comment: It would be helpful if you could let us see more messages you get on your console. In the mean time, you can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy. It seems it often requires a few extra steps when you use a proxy server.

Comment: Shouldn't your heroku be git@heroku.com:<repo-name> and not just git@heroku.com?