# app works on Heroku, but server error accessing DB through console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku that works fine when I access it through a browser. It's also displaying data from the database correctly. However, when I try to update the database through the console, I'm getting an internal server error message.  The model's name is Total.rb  (table's name is "totals") I'm doing this to get the first entry

> > t = Total.first
> >      !    Internal server error

Since the app's working through the browser, I'm not sure if this is a problem I'm causing or if it's heroku's fault. It's been a while since I updated through the console, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but that seems pretty straightforward.

I had always accessed the console with 'heroku console' now it's telling me to use 'heroku run console' but when I did that, it told me that the heroku gem has been deprecated and I need to install the Toolbelt. I installed the Toolbelt, authenticated, and tried to run a console session but same result.

Here's my Heroku info

Addons:        heroku-postgresql:dev
               pgbackups:plus
               zerigo_dns:basic

Dynos:         1
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:blahblah
Owner Email:   blahblah@gmail.com
Repo Size:     19M
Slug Size:     4M
Stack:         bamboo-mri-1.9.2
Web URL:       http://blahblah.com
Workers:       0

**Update**

If I try to run the console after installing the Heroku toolbelt, I get

```
 heroku run console
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.3213
bash: console: command not found
```

Comment: Very strange it works in browser.. Try `$ heroku run rake db:migrate` and see if that fixes it

Comment: Also restart heroku instance after migration. `$ heroku restart`

Comment: Heroku's telling me that the heroku gem's been deprecated and I need to install toolbelt, which I did. I authenticated, but I'm still getting the same result. See updated OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem there is some internal issue going on with the heroku CLI client that I don't understand.

The solution posted in this stackoverflow thread solved it for me:

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941659/running-heroku-console-does-not-start)

Comment: console only worked properly for me after I ran "heroku run bundle exec rails console"

Answer (score 0):

Could Total be a reserved word? You could try renaming the table or creating a temp one, then testing the same query with that. If nothing else it will eliminate one possible problem area.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Total being a reserved word. It worked before. See the updated OP. I think it has to do with the fact that the Heroku gem is deprecated. I installed the Toolbelt, as instructed, but I'm not sure what I need to be doing next to get console working properly.